# For an App, how to validate and sync ONLY mobile numbers from contact list?

Tags: android, mobile

I have checked the previous helpful suggestions on this topic and needed further clarity and help.

We are making a chat App. We require mobile number syncing from contacts. However my problem is here:

1. App can theoretically be used by anybody in the world. Let us say an US based user X has downloaded and is wanting to use it.
2. Once X registers, App starts syncing his contacts to display all of his contacts who are using this App.
3. X can have contacts from all over the world in his contact list and both landline and mobile numbers against various contacts.
4. For his US based contacts, X may have saved mobile numbers without countrycode, some with 001, some with country code +1.
5. For his foreign contacts, X may have saved landline/mobile number and those too in different formats (00 countrycode, + countrycode, with space, without space etc).

What i request help on is this:

When App starts syncing X's contacts to check if his contacts' mobile number also have my App (and this display that contact in my App's contacts), how do I check the individual contact's numbers, countrycodes and only mobile number? As going one country at a time is an inefficient way to do it, there must be some awesome solution here.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: If i understood your problem right, you should save each number along with it's country code on server while registering and while showing his contacts, check for the whole no. whether it matches with the one received from server or not.

Comment: I think I couldnt clarify myself. So let me try again.

1. X has registerd in my App with +1 1234567890.
2. After he is registered, App starts syncing his contacts and checking with my server which ones of his contact are on my App.
3. X has his friends 8976543210, 7896543210, +35 0654567329, +99 87954624, +44 032554678932 etc.
4. So I dont know which number is landline number and if in 3rd number listed above, 54567329 is the mobile number or 4567329 is the mobile number?
5. Similarly for other numbers.

Could I explain myself?

Comment: You can use Google's library to distinguish between numbers of different countries. https://github.com/google/libphonenumber Here's the link of this github library. https://github.com/MichaelRocks/libphonenumber-android (Specifically for android)